# Help ID this plant with balloon-like feature containing seeds

Tags: species-identification

I noticed this plant creeping over another [Ipomoea quamoclit](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b912) near my house in Kerala, South India. It has these balloon-like projections over them that break when popped. These projections do bear seeds. No visible flowers.

Leaves:
[image: The leaves]

The balloons:
[image: The balloon-like projections]

The seeds:
[image: The seeds, from popping the balloons]

EDIT: This plant is a creeper, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I searched Google for *Lantern plant* and came across this http://tabibito.hopto.org/display_one_file.php?article=494

[image]

Which is the same plant, but not the best of references, it doesn't give a scientific name and I am not sure Paper lantern plant is their right identification.

It is definitely of the genus *Physalis*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physalis

but as yet haven't been able to find the species that matches your leaf exactly. But I'd thought I'd post for now as it may help you, or others.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect it belongs to the *Physalis* genus too.

Comment: I don't think the leaves match,this not the exact species but sure it belongs to physalis